# How to get Paragraph from FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, paragraph

I am using a richtextbox in my app.

In the flowdocument, I have a table, inside which, I have tablerow group, again inside tablerow and then table cell.  Inside the table cell, I am using a paragraph with a specific name.  Later how I can get this paragraph by specifying the name using c# code?

How I will get all the paragraph which is having name and all those will be inside a table but in different table row and table cell?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the pargraphs are created (or accessed) place the paragraph in to a `Dictionary<string, Paragraph>()` using the name for its key, for later extraction via the key/name.